# Does there exist a unique closest natural number to each rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

So here's the question:

> Prove or disprove: For every $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, there is a unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which is the closest natural number to $x$.

I know we can define a rational number as $\frac{a}{b}$, with $a,b$ as natural numbers, but I'm not sure where to go from there. 
Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The uniqueness part has a problem with e.g. $\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: The claim is wrong. For $x=\frac32$, there is no unique closest natural number

Comment: so how would you prove its wrong? just with counter example?

Comment: @ZoeSoriano what if you restate this as "For every rational number $\frac{p}{q} \in \Bbb{Q}$ where $\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms and $q \neq 2$ then there is a unique $n \in \Bbb{N}$ that is closest to $\frac{p}{q}$

Comment: Yes, clearly the only candidates for $x = \frac{3}{2}$ are $1$ and $2$, and clearly they are equally close to $x$.

Comment: @quid, that is exactly how the question is worded in my book.

Comment: Is there at this place or somewhat before an explication what is meant by the closet integer? And/or what is the question in the bbok? Is it to decide if this is true, or to prove it is true? Also, which book?

Comment: @quid, my professor wrote the book. it says exactly: Prove or disprove that: For every x∈Q, there is a unique n∈N which is the closest natural number to x. It doesn't say anything about what it means to be a closest integer.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear then. I will expand the comments to a more detailed answer for you.

Comment: @quid, thank you very much! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not always a *unique* closest natural number, as mentioned in comments. In more detail:

If $q$ is a rational number of the form $q= a/2$ with $a$ an odd positive integer, then the two natural number $(a-1)/2$ and $(a+1)/2$ are both at distance $1/2$ from $q$. Every natural number other than these two is either less than $(a-1)/2$ or greater than $(a+1)/2$. Thus its distance to $q$ is strictly greater than $1/2$.

Therefore, the smallest distance from a natural number to such a $q$ is $1/2$. This distance is however attained by two natural numbers, $(a-1)/2$ and $(a+1)/2$, and therefore there is not always a unique closest natural number.